# Mobile Application - Wait for element / page to load

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, wait

I have a button which switches to my mobile application from the index.html to a different .html page. This is simply done by a href= bla bla. At the same time, a click-event is being triggered in a Javascript file.

However, I want to wait for the new .html page (if impossible I would like to wait till the desired div I want to access exists) to load before executing the desired function. I tried googling and ended up with miserable attempts with live(), on(), $(window).bind("load" .. - But none of those seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent 1x1 png in your target div.

```
$('img.myPNG').load(function(){ doThangs() });
```

Comment: $('#imgTarget').load(function(){ alert('hi') });    -   Doesn't give me an alert. (I added the image in the .html page, in the desired article.)